# A question on Abstract measure spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,M)$ be a measurable space
then 1) if $\mu $ and $\lambda $ are measures in $M$  st $\mu \ge $ $\lambda $ then show that $m$ defined as $\mu= \lambda + m $ is a measure

2) Prove that if $\lambda $ is $\sigma$ - finite $m$ is unique and show that in general $m$ is not unique but there is always a smallest such $m$

I couldn't do the 2nd part and didn't have any idea of doing it, any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Without any finite-ness condition, you could have points of infinity measure, say $\mu(\{x\})=\lambda(\{x\})=\infty$. Then $m(\{x\})$ may be arbitrarily defined. On the other hand, if the measure space is finite, can you show uniqueness? If yes, extend to the $\sigma$-finite case from there.